# How can I get all data of an array in controller Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I'm a beginner in Laravel, so my problem is that I want to display the data that an array contains. It's been a week that I try to solve it personally, but I do not get what I want.

This is a part of my controller:

```
  if ( !empty ( $nbrrowsol ) ) {
            for ($i=1; $i <=$nbrrowsol ; $i++) {
                # Code...
                $clients = DB::table('clients')->where('nom',$request->get('nomclient'))->first();
                $commercial=DB::table('commercials')->where('name',$request->get('commercial'))->first();

                $commande[] = array(
            'nom_client' => $request->get('nomclient')[$i],
            'organisme' => $request->get('organisme')[$i],
            'adresse' => $request->get('adresse')[$i],
            'email' => $request->get('email')[$i],
            'tel1' => $request->get('tel')[$i],
            'tel2' => $request->get('tel2')[$i],
            'fax' => $request->get('fax')[$i],
            'commercial' => $request->get('commercial')[$i],
            'date_reception' => $request->get('datereception')[$i],
            'date_prelevement' => $request->get('dateprelev')[$i],
            'saved_by' => $request->get('savedby')[$i],
            'code' => $request->get('codesol'.$i)[$i],
            'nature' => $request->get('naturesol'.$i)[$i]
                );
            }
  dd($commande);

        }
```

This is what I got in the console, but I didn't get the value:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide what is `$nbrrowsol` @Oussama

Comment: $nbrrowsol=$request->get('nbrrowsol');

Comment: So what is data inside `$nbrrowsol` is that array or what? Just show `dd($nbrrowsol)`. And also give `dd($request->all())`. Because you go through string in your `for`. Just give data from `request`...

Comment: $nbrrowsol contains a number

Comment: array:36 [▼ "_token" => "5pBe3cwHPNDkWq5im41FGVGV1PJDGKHdUoANvAkF7pz" "nomclient" => "client1" "organisme" => "ets" "adresse" => "stock" "email" => "email@test.com" "tel" => "+6456789" "tel2" => "+6864567" "fax" => "+3456789" "commercial" => "jamal" "datereception" => "2019-06-11" "dateprelev" => "2019-06-05" "savedby" => "responsable" "nbrrowsol" => "2" "codesol1" => "SOL201948" "naturesol1" => "SOL" "codesol2" => "SOL201949" "naturesol2" => "SOL" ]

Comment: So in your array you have 36 fields?? And you want to go trough `for` 2 times?

Comment: yes exactly: so to get array for 2 : [[nom client.................naturesol1][nom client .............naturesol2]]

Comment: Hmm... So you need first to go in array index than to data. I m not sure, but try to `dd($request->input('1.nomclient'))` and if you get `nomclient` that is what you need in your array, just instead of  1 you will have `$i`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below syntax for printing the data:

```
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($commande);
 die;
```

Or:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($commande->toArray());
die;
```

Comment: not working, itried that but i get this error Call to a member function toArray() on array

Comment: yes i tried it, but get the same result like in the picture on top

Comment: share the picture once again just because dd and print_r is working differently.

Comment: Pass request data here

Comment: i post a picture that contains result of print_r($commande); in answer

Comment: this is what i get after use : print_r($commande);    ====>Array ( [0] => Array ( [nom_client] => o [organisme] => l [adresse] => e [email] => o [tel1] => 2 [tel2] => 2 [fax] => 5 [commercial] => l [date_reception] => 0 [date_prelevement] => 0 [saved_by] => e [code] => O [nature] => O ) [1] => Array ( [nom_client] => u [organisme] => e [adresse] => k [email] => u [tel1] => 1 [tel2] => 1 [fax] => 3 [commercial] => y [date_reception] => 1 [date_prelevement] => 1 [saved_by] => s [code] => L [nature] => L ) )

Comment: You need to print here what you have in `$request->all()` before your if just `dd($request->all())`...

Comment: array:36 [▼
  "_token" => "5pBe3cwHPNDkWq5im41FGVGV1PJDGKHdUoANvAkF7pz"
  "nomclient" => "client1"
  "organisme" => "ets"
  "adresse" => "stock"
  "email" => "email@test.com"
  "tel" => "+6456789"
  "tel2" => "+6864567"
  "fax" => "+3456789"
  "commercial" => "jamal"
  "datereception" => "2019-06-11"
  "dateprelev" => "2019-06-05"
  "savedby" => "responsable"
  "nbrrowsol" => "2"
  "codesol1" => "SOL201948"
  "naturesol1" => "SOL"
  "codesol2" => "SOL201949"
  "naturesol2" => "SOL"
]